# Passing std::printf one format variable C++

Tags: c++, formatting, printf, std

Is there any way to pass `std::printf()` one format variable used multiple times? So, instead of writing this:

```cpp
std::printf("%c | %c | %c", '-', '-', '-');
```

I can just write this:

```cpp
std::printf("%c | %c | %c", '-');
```

A similar example is in Python, you can write:

```cpp
print("{} | {} | {}".format('-'))
```

At the moment, typing:

```cpp
std::printf("%c | %c | %c", '-');
```

prints out:

```
- | <unicode character I couldn't find> | <nothing>
```

Comment: `std::printf("- | - | -");`?

Comment: `print("{} | {} | {}".format('-'))` is not valid in Python, this will generate an error.

Comment: In Python, I get "IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple".

Comment: If you have access to it, you can use `std::format` (or `{fmt}`) too get something very similar to Python `.format()`.

Comment: C++20 `std::format` or C++23 `std::print("{0} | {0} | {0}", '-');`

Comment: I can't use ```std::printf("- | - | -"); ``` as I want to change the char from a '-' to a 'X' or 'O' for a tic tac toe game. I tried ```print("{} | {} | {}".format('-'))``` recently, and found it doesn't work in python. I used something like that once, but don't remember how.